# Sortable div with validation on the order of the child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

Consider the following div structure

---

`ELE 1` `div` `div` `div` `ELE 2` `div` `div` `ELE 3` `div`

---

I want to arrange the `ELE n`s in the order I want to. 
I figured out that I can use jQuery's `sortable()` function for the same.

But, I also want to do some **validations** and only if the validations are successful, can the dropped `div` occupy the new position. Otherwise it should revert to the original position.

**Validation Required :**

I want to move around and arrange `ELE 1`, `ELE 2` and `ELE 3`, but it should only work when their **order remains unchanged**.

For example, If `ELE 2` is dropped in a position after `ELE 3`, the drop should be cancelled

Any ideas?

**JSFiddle Link :** [**http://jsfiddle.net/neekdamon/C9kUM/1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/neekdamon/C9kUM/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very custom validation. But the way i would do it is by adding an `data-order` attribute to certain elements. So you can follow the original order.

When the order is changed you can do a check to see if the `data-order` attribute is still in the right numerical order. If not, do a revert.

I made an example of what i mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/C9kUM/2/

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, this will help me through! Thank you!